# Node.js: Error: 403 status code downloading tarball

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, npm, node-gyp

I was trying to install some modules in Nodejs, using NPM, but in some cases the install dont go on, and a error is returned:

```
Error: 403 status code downloading tarball
```

I got this again when I trying to install node-canvas:

```
D:\server\node_modules\canvas\node_modules\canvas>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.3/node-v0.8.3.tar.gz
gyp http 403 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.3/node-v0.8.3.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! rebuild error Error: 403 status code downloading tarball
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at Request.async (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:215:14)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:521:12)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:185:14)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (http.js:1445:7)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:111:23)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1356:20)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at TCP.onread (net.js:404:27)
gyp ERR! not ok
canvas@1.0.2 node_modules\canvas
```

I'm using Windows 7 64x
Nodejs 0.8.3

what could be this error?
What is 'tarball'?

Comment: A tarball is a `.tar` file, which is a sort of archive (like a zip file).  It seems for some reason that (for some odd reason) that the server (or an intermediate proxy server) has returned an HTTP 403 error (forbidden access), and has accordingly failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 403 means access is forbidden. Tarball is the `tar.gz` package file node is downloading for installation. It means that your ISP is restricting this site/URL `http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.3/node-v0.8.3.tar.gz`. If you are using proxy, ask your network administrator.